# Why does PHP require such an odd way to specify UTF-8?

Tags: php, html, utf-8

Accented characters weren't displaying in PHP so I added
**header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');**
to the header.  Still no joy.  But I've solved it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"');
?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html" charset=utf-8" / >
</head>
<body>
  Hélène
</body>
</html>

Notice the difference?  Why should a single double quote before the final single quote make all the difference?
If I drop the php making an html file and insert a double quote before utf-8 in the meta tag the way it should be then it doesn't work!
I'm using Chrome Version 88.0.4324.150 (Official Build) (64-bit) - haven't tested with other browsers.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This code doesn't work. You can't output a header after you already started outputting content. That also isn't valid syntax for the header. You should take a closer look at your testing as it does not appear to be valid.

Comment: "Why should a single double quote before the final single quote make all the difference?" - Well, occasionally two wrongs do make a right. Deliberating which typo was recovered is off-topic however.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question, but in any case, you can always use `<meta>` tag from HTML5

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```